# Updating values in an Access table when there are related records in other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database. I have been performing QAQC on this database. I have an updated version of one table that has been corrected and would like to write these corrections to the database. Unfortunately, some of the fixes involve records in two tables (as in, the key value connecting two tables was incorrect and needs to be changed). If I just open the database in Access, I can do this no problem. I can change one value, and then go into the related record in the other table, and change that value.

However, if I try to automate this in a script, when I try to send the UPDATE command to either table, it returns an error saying that I can't change or delete that record because a related record exists in the other table.

I am trying to do this in R using the odbc library and the dbExecute() function

Here is a toy example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Table1
Key1 Key2   valuea
---- ----   -----
1    a      2
1    b      2
2    b      2
2    c      2

Table2
Key1 Key2 valueb
---- ---- -----
1    a    10
1    a    12
1    b    3
1    b    72
2    b    23
2    b    24
2    c    7
2    c    6
```

the records where key1 = 1 and key2 = a are incorrect. The key2 value should be 'c', so that the tables, after being updated, should look like the following:

```
Table1
Key1 Key2   valuea
---- ----   -----
1    c      2
1    b      2
2    b      2
2    c      2

Table2
Key1 Key2 valueb
---- ---- -----
1    c    10
1    c    12
1    b    3
1    b    72
2    b    23
2    b    24
2    c    7
2    c    6
```

I'm trying to perform the following queries to try and make those changes:

```
"UPDATE Table1 SET Key2 = 'c' WHERE Key1 = 1 and Key2 = 'a'"
"UPDATE Table2 SET Key2 = 'c' WHERE Key1 = 1 and Key2 = 'a'"
```

Comment: Why is there no "c" Key2 in Table1? Why save Key2 in Table2?

Comment: Because it's a toy example. I don't exactly see why those questions are relevant, but I've expanded the toys to hopefully demonstrate why. I'd really rather avoid a discussion about why the database is structured the way it is. It can't be changed at this point.

Comment: What relations between Table1 and Table2. Is error issued when change order of UPDATE Table - first 2 then 1?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by editing the relationships in the Access Database. I selected the two tables in the "edit relationships" GUI, then made sure that both "enforce Referential integrity" and "Cascade Update Related Fields" were checked. After doing that, performing an UPDATE command on Table 1 would cascade the changes to table 2.